# Django newbie question: can't start a new project

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm totally new to django, and I'm using its documentation to get help on how to use it 
but seems like something is missing. i installed django using setup.py install command 
and i added the ( django/bin ) to system path variable but. i still cant start a new project
i use the following syntax to start a project :

`django-admin.py startproject myNewProject`


but it says

`Type 'django-admin.py help' for usage.

1`
 
UPDATES :
i use windows vista x64 . i checked the environment variables and i don't have DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable in there . should i add one ?? and with what value ?

do i miss anything ? 
thank u

Comment: When you typed `django-admin.py help` what did you see?  Anything interesting?

Comment: it said  type 'django.py help'  again

Comment: Please do the following.  (1) UPDATE your question with your platform (Windows or Linux). (2) UPDATE your question with the value of the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable, (3) RUN the `django-admin.py startproject...` command, (4) COPY the output, (5) UPDATE your question with the actual command and actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname

> This command is disabled when the --settings option to django-admin.py is used, or when the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE has been set. To re-enable it in these situations, either omit the --settings option or unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

Comment: i tried 'django-admin.py  settings' and help , but it still shows that message.

Answer (score 2):

do you have permission to write to the directory?

Comment: In that case it would be: Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have djagno or not and the it is in python path or not.if using linux  go to terminal type python  and then try to import django

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but...
Here is my answer:

I switched to directory `C:\Python27\Scripts\` and then typed:

```
python django-admin.py startproject MyProject
```

and it worked!